# Ambiguous Call Between Same Library?

Tags: c#, macos, asp.net-core, dnx

I am attempting to upgrade my ASP.NET 5 project from beta7 to beta8. I got the runtime and switched the various packages in my `project.json` over. Almost everything is compiling, except I'm getting a few errors that I have been unable to resolve.

In particular, this is the one that has me stumped and is preventing me from going forward:

```
DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'Microsoft.Data.Entity.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContextOptionsBuilder, string)' and 
'Microsoft.Data.Entity.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContextOptionsBuilder, string)'
```

at this line of code in my `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

I know in the past, this typically appears where another version of the library is in my GAC. However, I don't believe this to be the case on OSX. I did check my ~/.dnx/packages/ folder to see if anything jumped out at me, but nothing there either.

Here is my project.json for reference (some parts trimmed):

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "HtmlSanitizer": "2.0.5623.30465",
    "ImageProcessor": "2.3.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23225"
  },

  "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000 --ASPNET_ENV Development"
  },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
            }
         }
    },
    TRIMMED HERE
}
```

**UPDATE**
I am seeing one set of warnings in my `dnu build` that might indicate a possible problem.

`/Users/jasoncavett/Projects/web-cemeteries/obituaries/project.json(7,43): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer >= 7.0.0-beta8 but ended up with EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer 7.0.0-rc1-15945.
/Users/jasoncavett/Projects/web-cemeteries/obituaries/project.json(21,48): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc >= 1.0.0-beta8 but ended up with Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc 1.0.0-rc1-15824.
/Users/jasoncavett/Projects/web-cemeteries/obituaries/project.json(25,45): warning NU1007: Dependency specified was Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console >= 1.0.0-beta8 but ended up with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 1.0.0-rc1-15673.`

Comment: Unrelated to your question but I wanted to let you know that you should never need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime`. If you need that, something is wrong. You should add a reference to `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions` if you need something from the runtime

Comment: Did dnu restore give any warnings or errors. You can get this error if you had a reference to 2 different version of sqlserver

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci - Thanks. I have had this app awhile now, and generated a version from Yeoman, so it may have come in there. I don't believe I manually added it, but I'll look to remove it.

Comment: @ThomKiesewetter - There is nothing that I'm seeing. That's what is completely confusing me.

Comment: @ThomKiesewetter - I am seeing the warning displayed up above. I explicitly have beta8, but it looks like I'm being pushed up to rc1. Not sure why that is, but maybe it has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your nuget feed is from the release and not from the develop branch (most likely your problem)
You probably don't need this feed

```
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json
```

But I think you miss this feed

```
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/api/v3/index.json
```

Check your global.json for beta8

```
"sdk": {
  "version": "1.0.0-beta8"
 }
```

Check your dnvm if you set your active dnx is running beta8 before using dnu restore.

C:\git\DBC>dnvm list

```
Active Version         Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------         ------- ------------ --------------- -----
   1.0.0-beta4     clr     x86          win
   1.0.0-beta7     clr     x64          win
   1.0.0-beta7     clr     x86          win             b7
   1.0.0-beta7     coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-beta7     coreclr x86          win
   1.0.0-beta8     clr     x64          win
*  1.0.0-beta8     clr     x86          win             aa, b8
   1.0.0-beta8     coreclr x64          win
   1.0.0-beta8     coreclr x86          win
   1.0.0-rc1-15838 clr     x86          win             rc1a
```

If you has still has problems then check your for invalid reference project.json.

Comment: That was exactly it, Thom. I figured it out last night, but hadn't had a chance to post. My Nuget feeds were incorrect (and in wrong order to top it off). Switched that, and everything Just Worked(tm). Thanks for your help!